# question title in url like stackoverflow

Tags: .htaccess, url

Id like to make a url similar to stackoverflow where the user can type in a textbox and then on refresh a url is created.  like the url to this question uses the title i typed in. id like to make that effect on my own site.  thanks.  I think this may have to incorporate a .htaccess file??

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that the words from the title in the question URL don't affect where the URL goes. The following link goes to the same place: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366169/foo-bar-baz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366169/foo-bar-baz)

All you need to do is make your server process respond to the URL in the correct way. How you do this will depend on your chosen server architecture and/or programming language. Using `.htaccess` is unrelated.

Comment: since i dont have control over my server is there anyway i can generate directories with mkdir() and copy files in there to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link will help you understand how you can achieve your goal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ (django)

http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/ (php)

other web frameworks operate in similar way

in the given example you can interpret the url http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9701416/edit like this:

if you find "posts" in the url the next part of the url (9701416) is a parameter and the last part is the action so your main controller will load a post with id 9701416 and it will be loaded in edit mode (it doesn't mean there's a sub directory questions with sub directory 6366169 with a file "post")